# How to use Switch for more than one switchable arguments (in a compilable way)?

Tags: syntax, compile, built-in-symbols

Consider some example of usage of the function `Switch`:

```
func1[x_,y_, id_] := 
 Switch[id, 0, Exp[-x-y], 1, Exp[x+y], 2, 
  Exp[x-y], 3, Exp[y-x], _,0]
```

Could you please tell me how to use `Switch` for more than one switchable argument in a compilable way? For instance, for two arguments, let the definitions be

```
func2[x_,y_,0,1] = 1;
func2[x_,y_,0,2] = Exp[-2y];
func2[x_,y_,0,3]=Exp[-2x];
func2[x_,y_,1,2]=Exp[2x];
func2[x_,y_,1,3] = Exp[2x];
func2[x_,y_,2,3]=1;
```

I tried to come up with the following syntax which is unfortunately not compilable:

```
func2[x_, y_, id1_, id2_] := Switch[{id1, id2}, {0, 1}, 1, {_, _}, 0]
comp2 = Hold@
    Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {id1, _Integer}, {id2, \
_Integer}}, func2[x, y, id1, id2], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@func2 // ReleaseHold

<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@comp2
```

calls just `MainEvaluate` from the beginning.

This syntax, `func2[x_, y_, {id1_, id2_}]`, as well as similar modifications, also do not work.

Comment: Does this help?: `Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}},
  Switch[{x, y},
   {2, 2}, 7,
   _, 11]] // CompilePrint` -- You have to stick to the data types supported by the WVM. The catch-all blank being special syntax for `Switch` inside `Compile` (as is clear from the output of `CompilePrint`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : thanks! From your experience, how do you think, is it the fastest possible realization of switching between expressions in a compilable way?

Comment: As far as I know, `Switch` is implemented in `Compile` with a sequence of if-then-else statements. If instead you nested `Switch` (or `If`) statements, it should be faster for a large number of cases: `Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}},
 Switch[x,
  1, Switch[y,
   1, 17,
   2, 15,
   _, 11],
  2, Switch[y,
   1, 27,
   2, 25,
   _, 21],
  _, 31]]` -- But I've not done large or multiple switches. My experience is limited here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : thanks! It may be useful for my problem https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285359/evaluate-the-function-once-in-the-following-compiled-code-or-optimize-it .

Comment: @MichaelE2 : thanks! Your advise worked indeed much better than my initial attempt presented in this question. It is also much more transparent.