# Evaluate the function once in the following compiled code, or optimize it?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider the following `Switch` function for two variables:

```
IPcut = 25.;
IPcutID1[id1_, id2_] := 
 Switch[{id1, id2}, {11., -11.}, IPcut, {-11., 11.}, 
  IPcut, {-11., 13.}, IPcut, {13., -11.}, IPcut, {11., -13.}, 
  IPcut, {-13., 11.}, IPcut, {11., 211.}, IPcut, {211., 11.}, 
  IPcut, {-11., -211.}, IPcut, {-211., -11.}, IPcut, {11., 321.}, 
  IPcut, {321., 11.}, IPcut, {-11., -321.}, IPcut, {-321., -11.}, 
  IPcut, {11., 2.}, IPcut, {2., 11.}, IPcut, {-11., -2.}, 
  IPcut, {-2., -11.}, IPcut, {11., 21.}, IPcut, {21., 11.}, 
  IPcut, {-11., -21.}, IPcut, {-21., -11.}, IPcut, {-13., 13.}, 
  IPcut, {13., -13.}, IPcut, {13., 211.}, IPcut, {211., 13.}, 
  IPcut, {-13., -211.}, IPcut, {-211., -13.}, IPcut, {13., 321.}, 
  IPcut, {321., 13.}, IPcut, {-13., -321.}, IPcut, {-321., -13.}, 
  IPcut, {13., 2.}, IPcut, {2., 13.}, IPcut, {-13., -2.}, 
  IPcut, {-2., -13.}, IPcut, {13., 21.}, IPcut, {21., 13.}, 
  IPcut, {-13., -21.}, IPcut, {-21., -13.}, IPcut, {-211., 211.}, 
  IPcut, {211., -211.}, IPcut, {-211., 321.}, IPcut, {321., -211.}, 
  IPcut, {211., -321.}, IPcut, {-321., 211.}, IPcut, {-211., 2.}, 
  IPcut, {2., -211.}, IPcut, {211., -2.}, IPcut, {-2., 211.}, 
  IPcut, {-211., 21.}, IPcut, {21., -211.}, IPcut, {211., -21.}, 
  IPcut, {-21., 211.}, IPcut, {-321., 321.}, IPcut, {321., -321.}, 
  IPcut, {321., -2.}, IPcut, {-2., 321.}, IPcut, {-321., 2.}, 
  IPcut, {2., -321.}, IPcut, {321., -21.}, IPcut, {-21., 321.}, 
  IPcut, {-321., 21.}, IPcut, {21., -321.}, IPcut, {2., -2.}, 
  IPcut, {-2., 2.}, IPcut, {2., -21.}, IPcut, {-21., 2.}, 
  IPcut, {-2., 21.}, IPcut, {21., -2.}, IPcut, {21., -21.}, 
  IPcut, {-21., 21.}, IPcut, {22., 22.}, IPcut, {130., 130.}, 
  IPcut, {130., 22.}, IPcut, {22., 130.}, IPcut, _, 0]
```

Next, consider some test data:

```
IPrand = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^7, 2}];
pairs = RandomInteger[{0, 500}, {100, 2}] // N;
```

Next, consider some test routine:

```
routine1 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{IPrand, _Real, 1}, {j, _Integer}, {pairs, _Real, 2}}, 
      Module[{ips, id1, id2, ipcut, count, len},
       count = 0.;
       ips = Compile`GetElement[IPrand, 1];
       len = Length[pairs];
       id1 = Compile`GetElement[pairs, j, 1];
       id2 = Compile`GetElement[pairs, j, 2];
       ipcut = IPcutID1[id1, id2](*(id1+id2)*);
       Do[
        count += Boole[ips > ipcut], {i, 1, len, 1}];
       count
       ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. DownValues@IPcutID1 /. 
   OwnValues@IPcut // ReleaseHold
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@routine1;
```

where in this string:

```
ipcut = IPcutID1[id1, id2](*(id1 + id2)*);
```

we may comment either `id1 + id2` or `IPcutID1[id1, id2]`. `CompilePrint` does not show `MainEvaluate`, but a lot of `CompareTensor` calls. The latter may suggest that `IPcutID1[id1, id2]` is a very dumb realization.

However, my stupid expectation was that `IPcutID1[id1, id2]` evaluates only once, and it does not care whether `IPcutID1` is fast or slow. These expectations failed though, as the runtime with uncommented `IPcutID1[id1, id2]` is 20 times larger than with commented `IPcutID1[id1, id2]`, which suggests that it evaluates many times.

Could you please tell me how (without modifying the structure of `routine1`) to evaluate it really once still inside `Module`, or to optimize the initial function `IPcutID1`?

**Edit**

Following [the suggestion of MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285275/how-to-use-switch-for-more-than-one-switchable-arguments-in-a-compilable-way), I rewrote `IPcutID1` as

```
IPcutID2[id1_, id2_] := 
 Switch[id1, 11., 
  Switch[id2, -11., IPcut, -13., IPcut, 211., IPcut, 321., IPcut, 2., 
   IPcut, 21., IPcut, _, 0], -11., 
  Switch[id2, 11., IPcut, 13., IPcut, -211., IPcut, -321., IPcut, -2.,
    IPcut, -21., IPcut, _, 0], 13., 
  Switch[id2, -11., IPcut, -13., IPcut, 211., IPcut, 321., IPcut, 2., 
   IPcut, 21., IPcut, _, 0], -13., 
  Switch[id2, 11., IPcut, 13., IPcut, -211., IPcut, -321., IPcut, -2.,
    IPcut, -21., IPcut, _, 0], 211., 
  Switch[id2, 11., IPcut, 13., IPcut, -211., IPcut, -321., IPcut, -2.,
    IPcut, -21., IPcut, _, 0], -211., 
  Switch[id2, -11., IPcut, -13., IPcut, 211., IPcut, 321., IPcut, 2., 
   IPcut, 21., IPcut, _, 0], 2., 
  Switch[id2, 11., IPcut, 13., IPcut, -211., IPcut, -321., IPcut, -2.,
    IPcut, -21., IPcut, _, 0], -2., 
  Switch[id2, -11., IPcut, -13., IPcut, 211., IPcut, 321., IPcut, 2., 
   IPcut, 21., IPcut, _, 0], 21., 
  Switch[id2, 11., IPcut, 13., IPcut, -211., IPcut, -321., IPcut, -2.,
    IPcut, -21., IPcut, _, 0], -21., 
  Switch[id2, -11., IPcut, -13., IPcut, 211., IPcut, 321., IPcut, 2., 
   IPcut, 21., IPcut, _, 0], 130., 
  Switch[id2, 130., IPcut, 22., IPcut, _, 0], 22., 
  Switch[id2, 130., IPcut, 22., IPcut, _, 0], _, 0]
```

This function is much faster. However, it is still interesting for me how to call the function once.

Comment: That sure is some ugly code you have there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of all this. And frankly, I am quite confused by your elaborate way of code injection (which IMHO just asks for trouble).
So I might get something wrong. But why don't you just use `Integers` for `pairs`?

```
routine2 = With[{IPcut = 25},
   Compile[{{IPrand, _Real, 1}, {j, _Integer}, {pairs, _Integer, 2}},
    Module[{ips, id1, id2, ipcut, count, len},
     count = 0;
     ips = Compile`GetElement[IPrand, 1];
     len = Length[pairs];
     id1 = Compile`GetElement[pairs, j, 1];
     id2 = Compile`GetElement[pairs, j, 2];
     
     ipcut = Switch[
       id1,
       11,
       Switch[id2, -11, IPcut, -13, IPcut, 211, IPcut, 321, IPcut, 2, IPcut, 21, IPcut, _, 0],
       -11,
       Switch[id2, 11, IPcut, 13, IPcut, -211, IPcut, -321, IPcut, -2, IPcut, -21, IPcut, _, 0],
       13,
       Switch[id2, -11, IPcut, -13, IPcut, 211, IPcut, 321, IPcut, 2, IPcut, 21, IPcut, _, 0],
       -13,
       Switch[id2, 11, IPcut, 13, IPcut, -211, IPcut, -321, IPcut, -2, IPcut, -21, IPcut, _, 0],
       211,
       Switch[id2, 11, IPcut, 13, IPcut, -211, IPcut, -321, IPcut, -2, IPcut, -21, IPcut, _, 0],
       -211,
       Switch[id2, -11, IPcut, -13, IPcut, 211, IPcut, 321, IPcut, 2, IPcut, 21, IPcut, _, 0],
       2,
       Switch[id2, 11, IPcut, 13, IPcut, -211, IPcut, -321, IPcut, -2, IPcut, -21, IPcut, _, 0],
       -2,
       Switch[id2, -11, IPcut, -13, IPcut, 211, IPcut, 321, IPcut, 2, IPcut, 21, IPcut, _, 0],
       21,
       Switch[id2, 11, IPcut, 13, IPcut, -211, IPcut, -321, IPcut, -2, IPcut, -21, IPcut, _, 0],
       -21,
       Switch[id2, -11, IPcut, -13, IPcut, 211, IPcut, 321, IPcut, 2, IPcut, 21, IPcut, _, 0],
       130,
       Switch[id2, 130, IPcut, 22, IPcut, _, 0],
       22,
       Switch[id2, 130, IPcut, 22, IPcut, _, 0],
       _, 
       0
       ];
     
     Do[count += Boole[ips > N[ipcut]], {i, 1, len, 1}];
     
     count
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
    ]
   ];
```

Then this runs much faster:

```
IPrand = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {10^7, 2}];
pairs = RandomInteger[{0, 500}, {100, 2}];
a1 = routine1[IPrand, 1, pairs]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a2 = routine2[IPrand, 1, pairs]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a1 == a2
```

> 3.5444
>
> 0.053489
>
> True

This might have to do with the fact that the outcome is pretty boring:

```
MinMax[a2]
```

> {100, 100}

So the C compiler *might* have been able to optimize away all logic at compile time.

Another potential reason why this is so much faster: The C compiler is proablaby able to build a jump table or some other fast lookup structure if all the cases in the `Switch`s are of integral type. (I have not checked the generated assembler code, though.)

Btw.: *Mathematica* does not convert `Switch` to C' s `switch`, but the compiler may generate a jump table nonetheless.